# Disabling every html DOM element excluding specific #id

Tags: jquery, html

Actually I am trying to disable all element in html page, but there are some element which i want to be active.

```
$('body').find('*').attr('onclick',"return false;"); //Disabling all elements
// Trying to make this id("prerequisitedetails") active.
$("#prerequisitedetails").parents().attr('onclick',null).off('click');
```

Can anyone tell me proper way to do this.

Comment: Do not set events with attr. Attaching an event to every element is going to be SLOW.

Comment: @epascarello: Took Chrome 23.494ms to attach a click handler to `$(document.body).find("*")` on this page. :-) Mind you, this page isn't all that busy... Took 78.205ms on http://api.jquery.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me proper way to do this.

Don't use `onclick` attributes, use real event handlers.

This should do it:

```
$('body')
    .find('*')
    .not($("#prerequisitedetails").parents().addBack())
    .click(false);
```

What that does:

- Finds all elements that are descendants of `body`
- From that set, removes ones that are the `prerequisitedetails` element or any of its parents. Note the `addBack` so we're including the element itself.
- Uses the jQuery shorthand for a click handler that returns false.

Although thinking about it, are you **sure** you want to allow clicks on the element's *parents* rather than its *descendants*? You may want:

```
$('body')
    .find('*')
    .not($("#prerequisitedetails").find("*").addBack())
    .click(false);
```

That's like the above, but the elements it leaves "enabled" are the `prerequisitedetails` element and its descendants.

It's a bit brute-force, though. You might look for questions and answers related to modal dialogs, which typically use a shim element that capture the clicks, and then position the element you want to have "above" that in front of that element using `z-index`.

Comment: or `find(":not(#prerequisitedetails)")`

Comment: @Ankit: OP seemed to also want to allow clicks on the parents. (Although it seems to me parents doesn't make much sense; *descendants* does, though.)

Comment: I think they both makes equal sense.OP is removing click from the ancestors and you from descendants. Isn't it??

Comment: Tenq.. You solve all my problem. Actually your second answer is more appropriate for my issue.

Comment: @Ankit: Right. But think about it: `<body><button id="prerequisitedetails" type="button">Click <em>here</em></button></body>` It doesn't make sense to re-enable `body`. It *does* make sense to re-enable the `em` element.